# How to fix this issue in Window 7: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine?

Tags: windows-7, internet

I get this error when a program I am using opens a website:
"An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine"

I found this but it doesn't seem to exist in Windows 7:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/204594

When I go to network, there is no "Bindings". Not sure if Microsoft is even updating these pages, they seem outdated.

Comment: The linked KB article doesn't apply to Windows 7, because it's targeted at "Microsoft Windows NT Workstation 4.0 Developer Edition, Microsoft Windows NT Server 4.0 Standard Edition", as written in the "Applies To" section. What's the program you're using?

Comment: Autodesk Maya. Because that's the page the support sent me. I found another link and that seems to work. I will have to see if that error pops up again as it's not always.

Comment: Which version? Also, what link are you talking about? If you were to solve the issue, that might help others as well.

Comment: Maya 2014. I used this link to find wins and then disable it like the original link said: http://answers.vt.edu/kb/entry/1316/

Comment: Are you using a third-party firewall or the built-in one?